# Scroll position for bottom end of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to do an endless scrolling for my web application. In order to do action while reaching bottom side of page I tried this code:

```
var count = 2;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        alert("REached page down");
        search(false, count);
        count++;
    }
});
```

But unfortunately this is being called when I scroll to topmost side of page. I tried to return scroll position as a onclick event to the bottom most div of my page which returned :

```
$(window).scrollTop() as 1614
$(document).height() as 2250
$(window).height() as 2250.
```

Any other ways to achieve it?

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ybfbn68m/

Comment: Yeah me too got it from a working sample. But I dont understand why its not working here!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for page bottom with this code.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 500) {
  // fun stuff goes here
}
```

`500` is the offset value from the bottom, as you might want to trigger your code a bit earlier to prepare content.

For example, [hipster.cc](http://hipster.cc/) uses the same code for endless scrolling.

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried this its calling whenever I scroll up or down.